# Multivariate normal distributions density function: What is the value if the determinant is zero?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

Given a function that calculates a multivariate normal distribution, what value should be returned if the determinant of the covariance matrix is zero? What does it mean if this is the case?

Edit (I hope this makes it clearer):

I have data that is assumed to be described by a MVN distribution.

[image]

Now I want to sum over this the results of the data to get the likelihood.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "calculate" and "value"? Is this function supposed to give (a) a *density*, (b) a (cumulative) *probability*, (c) a random variate from the function, or (d) something else?

Comment: The density, it's basically what the function dmvnorm in the package R package mvtnorm does. http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/mvtnorm/html/Mvnorm.html

Comment: When the determinant is zero, the density is undefined.  Here's an (extremely efficient) `R` implementation: `dmvnorm.singular <- function(...) return(NA)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Return value for your function

If you want to write code for a function that computes a multivariate normal distribution, then, in case the determinant of the var-covar is zero, this return-value is undefined because the var-covar matrix is singular (the inverse does not exist).

Probably the best return value for your function, in case the var-covar matrix is singular, is NA.

### Reasons for singular var-covar matrix

The reasons for singularity could be that one of your 'variables' is (as good as) constant such that its variance is (almost) zero, or it could also be that one of your variables is a linear combination of the other variables.

Comment: Please tell us what you understand the "value returned" to be. The correctness of your answer depends on this. For instance, your statement will be wrong for any readers who interpret "value" as the distribution function.

Comment: @whuber: I see what you mean but the asker of the question wrote: "Given a function that calculates a multivariate normal distribution, what value should be returned if the determinant of the covariance matrix is zero" and I just answered to that; apparently he has some function and he wants to know what value this function should return.  My answer is that the return value is undefined etc... I will change my answer to be more clear about this

Comment: Normally, when someone refers to a "distribution" as a function, they mean literally that: the distribution function, *aka* cumulative distribution function. That's because in general a density does not have to exist. Since it does not exist in this case, the default understanding of many readers will be that this question asks for the CDF. That *is* well-defined, as it is for *all* distributions. I appreciate your attempt at clarification, but I still cannot see anything in your answer that makes this essential distinction between a distribution function and its density.

Comment: well if someone says 'if I want to write code for a function' then I don't see why that might not be interpreted (that is how I interpreted it) 'if I wanted to write code for an R-function'.  But the only way to find out is to ask @Danu ?

Comment: Certainly one can write an `R` function to return the values of the distribution function. One could also write an `R` function to return the *density* of a degenerate multivariate distribution, given as input a coordinate expressed with respect to a basis spanning the singular support of that distribution.  Regardless of what might or might not be possible in software, the question of *which* function this code should calculate is still at issue.

Answer (score 4):

Presume that the covariance matrix as specified is n by n, i.e., the Multivariate Normal random variable X is in n dimensions.  Det(covariance matrix) = 0 if and only if the covariance matrix is singular.  If the covariance matrix is singular, X does not have a density.  There may exist a lower dimensional space (manifold) in which X is concentrated, such that the covariance matrix in that lower dimensional space is nonsingular, in which case X, when projected into that lower dimensional space, would have a density.

Edit: Pertaining to whuber's comment above, based on the thread title, I was presuming the OP wants to know (how to compute) the density.  The cumulative probability distribution does exist, even if the covariance matrix is singular (has determinant = 0), and could be computed by integrating the lower dimensional density.  I believe the only way that there could not be a lower dimensional manifold on which X was concentrated and which had nonsingular covariance, is if X were concentrated at a single point (for example, a one dimensional Normal having variance = 0), in whuch case the cumulative distribution = 1 for any region containing that point, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it can also be defined by the use of generalized inverse and "pseudo-determinant".

Solution is not unique though.

Comment: This does not appear to answer OP's question. Could you please expand your answer to directly address what is implied if the determinant of a covariance matrix is 0?